# Using addVars and addConstrs in Gurobi

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, gurobi

I am pretty new to modeling with Gurobi/python interface. I have written the complete code however there is something in constraints no 6. I am sharing part of my code that is causing trouble.  I hope anyone gets in touch with me and discuss with me this piece of code to get the variables as I intend to.

[required constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDLNu.png),

[the f parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHJnv.png),

[the required variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWY7n.png)

```
from gurobipy import GRB,quicksum,Model

m = Model ('sab')
# all nodes in the network
N = list(range(0,27))
# no of requests 
R = [i for i in range(1,6)] # Requests 
# Transfer nodes for each request
Cr = {1: [12,13,14], 2: [15,16,17], 3: [18,19,20], 4: [21,22,23], 5:[24,25,26] }
# parameter f
[description of f][1]as shown in the image, I do not know how to code it correctly

# variables [variable description][1] 
for r in R:
    yr = m.addVars(R,N,N, vtype=GRB.BINARY)

for r in R:
    z = m.addVars(Cr[r],Cr[r],vtype=GRB.BINARY)
    m.update()

# constraint no 6 [enter image description here][1]
for r in R:
    m.addConstrs(((quicksum(yr[i,j] for j in N if j !=i) + quicksum(z [i,j] for j in Cr[r] if j !=i)- quicksum(yr[j,i] for j in N if j !=i)- quicksum(z [j,i] for j in Cr[r]if j !=i ) == f) for i in Cr[r] ),'6')
```

Comment: Please only post [MREs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your code, it's unclear what `N` is and `Crn` should most likely be `Cr`, right?

Comment: @mattmilten  I have added some more information along with three images (see links) that clarify the parameter f ,  two set of variables and constraints no 6.

Comment: I mainly face problem coding the parameter f and coding constraint no 6.
I can share the whole code and the model itself